# How to rearrange array object into key value pairs using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If my Array object looks like this :

```
["pi|sgm", "pi|db", "pi|dlm", "groups|Homesign", "groups|Speakers", "groups|Co-speech Gesture", "pubyear|36"]
```

How can I split them into multiple array based on their first element. For example, I need the new Array like this:

```
["pi":["sgm", "db", "dlm"], "groups":["Homesign", "Speakers", "Co-speech Gesture"], "pubyear":["36"]]
```

Can we do this operation using jQuery?

Comment: The `key: value` syntax is of an `Object`, and not of an `Array`.

Comment: I am trying to just create Object our of given Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method with [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```js
var data = ["pi|sgm", "pi|db", "pi|dlm", "groups|Homesign", "groups|Speakers", "groups|Co-speech Gesture", "pubyear|36"];

// iterate over the element to reduce to an object
var res = data.reduce(function(obj, v) {
  // split the value by delimiter `|`
  var spl = v.split('|');
  // define the property as an array if already not defined
  obj[spl[0]] = obj[spl[0]] || [];
  // push the value to the array
  obj[spl[0]].push(spl[1]);
  // return the object reference
  return obj;
  // set initial value as an empty object for the result
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

---

Or using  [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method with the same logic.

```js
var data = ["pi|sgm", "pi|db", "pi|dlm", "groups|Homesign", "groups|Speakers", "groups|Co-speech Gesture", "pubyear|36"];

// initialize object for result
var res = {};
// iterate over the element 
data.forEach(function(v) {
  // split the value by delimiter `|`
  var spl = v.split('|');
  // define the property as an array if already not defined
  res[spl[0]] = res[spl[0]] || [];
  // push the value to the array
  res[spl[0]].push(spl[1]);
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: which one is the best performer?

Comment: @Milson :  not sure about the performance.... anyway there would be a slight difference which is negligible...